# jQuery: Active state: AddClass to a link that contains the document.href as href

Tags: javascript, jquery, location-href

I'm wondering if its possible to addClass to a link, that has the same href as the document.href?

I tried, but without any luck.

```
if ($("a").attr("href") == document.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

Isn't this possible??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return this.href === document.location.href;
}).addClass("active");
```

Should work.

Comment: I was gonna do an each but yeah, filter does the trick even better.

Comment: Thanks!! :-D It really was possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href=" + document.location.href + "]").addClass("active");
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried window.location.href instead of document.location.href?